# Linksys Router not connecting to internet through switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, switch

I am setting up a new Linksys WRT610N router, and I connected it to my Apple Airport Extreme, and it connected to the internet perfectly. But I set up a Netgear GS108 switch, connected it to the modem, and connected the Apple Airport Extreme and Linksys WRT610 router to the switch and the Apple Airport Extreme works fine like before, but the Linksys WRT610 router does not connect to the internet!

I tried using different LAN cables and plugging the LAN cable to different ports of the switch, but no matter what, the router does not connect to the internet although I can join the wifi network and on the router the green internet circle is blinking.

What happened? Also, I am using a late 2013 Macbook pro if it is a client issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ISP is only giving you a single IP address. When you put a switch to the modem and connect multiple devices WAN ports to the switch as peers, only one will get an Internet address from the ISP.

You need to pick which layer-3 (routing) device will be your connection to the modem, and any other devices need to be connected behind that device.

Comment: OOOOOH... so then if I unplug the apple Airport and plug it into the Linksys then the Linksys will work?!  THANKS!!!!!!!

Comment: I wish I had enough reputation to upvote this question xD

Comment: I plugged it in the router, but it still doesn't connect to the internet :(

Comment: How are you connecting this?

Comment: connecting linksys directly to modem with LAN

Comment: Plug the Linksys WAN port into the modem (you may or may not need to disconnect the modem for a short period of time). The Linksys may need to be properly configured for PPPoE or whatever authentication your ISP may be using. Then you can plug whatever you want for your local network into the Linksys LAN port(s). You may want to set the Airport as a bridge instead of a router in order to eliminate double-NAT.

Comment: Well Im using the linksys to port forward xD

Comment: The Linksys will not request an IP address except on the WAN port. You can do port forwarding on the Linksys, but it forwards from the WAN to the LAN, and it NATs from the LAN to the WAN. The WAN port needs to be connected to the modem, and anything in your network needs to be connected to the LAN. When you make changes like this, you will need to get new DHCP from the Linksys instead of the Airport. The Airport should probably configured as a bridge so that the Linksys port forwarding will work (double-NAT will kill the port forwarding).

Comment: what is WAN? :P

Comment: WAN is Wide Area Network. It is the Interface toward the Internet (your modem). The Linksys should have a single WAN port, and one or more LAN ports. The WAN port must be connected to the modem.

Answer (score 0):

If your Linksys router is not connecting to the internet, there are a few things you can check.

- First, make sure your router is plugged in and properly connected to your modem and router.
- Next, make sure your internet is working by checking your ISP’s website.
- If your internet is still not working, you may need to reset your router.
- To reset your router, turn it off and then on again by pressing the reset button.
- If that doesn’t work, you may replace the router.
- You can follow more steps to check if your [Linksys router won't work](https://fixotip.com/error-linksys-router-is-not-working-how-to-fix/).